# show there has to be finite set of subsequences...

Tags: sequences-and-series

I thought I got sequences but I can't figure out this problem:

Given is a sequence $a=\{a_n\}$ and a **finite** set of subsequences $a^1, a^2, ... ,a^l$ (it's not to the power of ..), such that the union of the index sets of the subsequences equal the index set of $a$. We assume that every subsequence has the same limit $g \in \mathbb{R}$.

Show that sequence also has limit $g$.

The other related question is: Give an example of an **infinite** set of subsequences that all have the same limit $g \in \mathbb{R}$, but such that the original sequence does not converge.

So in other words show that it is necessary to have **finite** set of subsequences.

Comment: I was confused at first about this problem, but to anyone else who might be confused, the crucial point seems to be that the indices of the subsequence cover the indices of the original sequence, i.e. if the original sequence is indexed by $A$, and $a^r$ ($r=1,2,\ldots,l$) is indexed by $A^r$, then $A=\cup_{r=1}^l A_r$.

Answer (score 2):

I will use a less confusing notation. Let $\{a_n\}$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$, be your sequence. I will denote a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ as $\{a_{n_i}\}$ where $I_i=\{n_i\}\subset \mathbb{N}$. Then assuming $\cup_{i=1}^m I_i = \mathbb{N}$, i.e. there are $m$ subsequences (finite number of subsequences) which all converge to $g$, we want to prove $\{a_n\}$ converges to $g$.

A sequence converges to $g$ if for any $\epsilon$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$, we have $a_n\in B_\epsilon(g)$. Now since $\{a_{n_i}\}$ all converge to $g$, for any $\epsilon$ there are $N_1, N_2, \cdots, N_m$ such that $a_{n_i}\in B_\epsilon(g)$ if $n_i>N_i$ (by convergence of subsequence $\{a_{n_i}\}$ to $g$). Take $N=\max(N_1, \cdots, N_m)$ (here you are using finiteness). Then for any $n>N$ you have $a_n\in B_{\epsilon}(g)$. So $\{a_n\}$ converges to $g$.

Answer (score 2):

As for a counter-example of why it fails for an infinite number of subsequences (I will be using Hamed's notation), take

$$a_n = (-1)^n.$$

For even $n$, this constitutes a subsequence that converge to $1$. Let $I_1,I_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of index sets in $\mathbb{N}$, such that:

- $2i-1\in I_i$.
- No other odd numbers are contained in $I_i$.
- $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} I_i = \mathbb{N}$.

Certainly each subsequence $\{a_{n_i}\}_{n_i\in I_i}$ converges to $1$, but $a_n$ itself does not converge.